# Read sections from file with Python

Tags: python, cisco-ios

I'm trying to convert the cisco running configuration into parameters using python, and i'm stuck at reading configuration sections with python.
Say for instance you have the below stanza:

```
!
interface Async1
 no ip address
 encapsulation slip
!       
router bgp 65500
 bgp router-id 1.1.1.1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 timers bgp 10 30
 neighbor 1.2.3.4 remote-as 1234
 neighbor 1.2.3.4 description Some Description
 neighbor 1.2.3.4 update-source GigabitEthernet0/0
 !
 address-family ipv4
  network 2.2.2.2 mask 255.255.255.255
  network 3.3.3.0 mask 255.255.255.252
  neighbor 1.2.3.4 activate
  neighbor 1.2.3.4 allowas-in 3
  neighbor 1.2.3.4 prefix-list PXL out
 exit-address-family
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
```

I want to read lines from 'router bgp' until first line that starts with '!' (e.g ^!), and then re-read the block to extract parameters into variables.
A sample output would be:

```
router bgp 65500
 bgp router-id 1.1.1.1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 timers bgp 10 30
 neighbor 1.2.3.4 remote-as 1234
 neighbor 1.2.3.4 description Some Description
 neighbor 1.2.3.4 update-source GigabitEthernet0/0
 !
 address-family ipv4
  network 2.2.2.2 mask 255.255.255.255
  network 3.3.3.0 mask 255.255.255.252
  neighbor 1.2.3.4 activate
  neighbor 1.2.3.4 allowas-in 3
  neighbor 1.2.3.4 prefix-list PXL out
 exit-address-family
!
```

Note: I am able to extract the above code using awk or grep, but I want to translate my bash code to Python.

Thanks!

Comment: It may be useful for you to read this question and answer about using a customer field separator. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600475/how-to-read-records-terminated-by-custom-separator-from-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

bgp = confparse.find_blocks(r"^router bgp 65500")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to another post on stackoverflow, I found a way to extract configuration sections from running config. Post is at [Reading a file for a certain section in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417197/reading-a-file-for-a-certain-section-in-python).

Working code to extract "router bgp" section below:

```
bgp_found = False

bgp_section = []

with open('running-config', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'router bgp' in line:
            bgp_found = True
            bgp_section.append(str(line).rstrip('\n'))  # this will append the section start to list
            continue
        if bgp_found:
            if line.startswith('!'):  # this will test if line starts with '!'
                bgp_found = False
            else:
                bgp_section.append(str(line).rstrip('\n'))
print (bgp_section)  # just for testing purposes; list would be used to extract rest of parameters
```

Hope it will be useful for others as well.