# How do I read only a part of a file in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, file-io

food.txt

```
~ Oils, Vinegars and Condiments

-- Oils: canola oil, extra-virgin olive oil, toasted sesame
-- Vinegars: balsamic, distilled white, red wine, rice
-- Ketchup
-- Mayonnaise
-- Dijon mustard
-- Soy sauce
-- Chili paste
-- Hot sauce
-- Worcestershire

====================================
~ Seasonings

-- Kosher salt

-- Black peppercorns

-- Dried herbs and spices: bay leaves, cayenne pepper, crushed red pepper, cumin, ground coriander, oregano, paprika, rosemary, thyme leaves, cinnamon, cloves, allspice, ginger, nutmeg

-- Spice blends: chili powder, curry powder, Italian seasoning

-- Vanilla extract
====================================
~
Canned Goods and Bottled Items

-- Canned beans: black, cannellini, chickpeas, kidney

-- Capers

-- Olives

-- Peanut butter

-- Preserves or jelly

-- Low-sodium stock or broth

-- Canned tomatoes

-- Tomatoes, canned and paste

-- Salsa

-- Tuna fish


====================================
```

How do you read only:

```
~ Oils, Vinegars and Condiments

-- Oils: canola oil, extra-virgin olive oil, toasted sesame
-- Vinegars: balsamic, distilled white, red wine, rice
-- Ketchup
-- Mayonnaise
-- Dijon mustard
-- Soy sauce
-- Chili paste
-- Hot sauce
-- Worcestershire
```

filereader.py

```
import re

regex = (r"^(~\WOil.*)$", r"^=*=$")
with open(filename, "r") as file_handler:
        # Print section of file as String
```

I just don't know what to do. I get error and blanks when using find() from String Obj and seek() from File object.

References: [How do I read a specific line of a .txt file with Python 3? I only want to read one line and save it as a variable and not all the lines.](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-read-a-specific-line-of-a-txt-file-with-Python-3-I-only-want-to-read-one-line-and-save-it-as-a-variable-and-not-all-the-lines?share=1) and [Reading a file for a certain section in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417197/reading-a-file-for-a-certain-section-in-python)

Comment: It seems like you want just the first part. Why not just `if "======" in line: break` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regex for this. Just read until you find the section separator:

```
with open('food.txt') as f:
    for line in iter(f.readline, '====================================\n'):
        print(line, end='')
```

If you want to save the text as a variable:

```
with open('food.txt') as f:
    text = ''.join(iter(f.readline, '====================================\n'))
```

To get rid of the extra empty line at the end:

```
text = text.strip()
```